# C# Antivirus-Program using MD5 - BackgroundWorker/FileNotFoundException - Incorrect Path?

Tags: c#, winforms, md5, backgroundworker, .net

I'm trying to create an antivirus program that takes a group of 5 MD 5 hashes from a text file and after the user select a folder using browse and clicks scan the program should iterate through all the files run the hash for each one in a background worker and compare, if the result is a virus detected, the result is then fed to a list box.

Currently the code is catching (FileNotFoundException) and the msgbox displaying FilePath is producing "Path1" "Path2" "Path3", could anyone explain how i can correct the code so that the paths are being correctly fed? I don't really understand where the "Path1" "Path2" "Path3" ect is coming from?

Code Below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace TestAntivirus
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int noofvirus = 0;
        List<string> completehashes = new List<string>();

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        label1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        noofvirus = 0;
        label2.Text = "Viruses:" + noofvirus.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void BDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void BScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] scanned = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int numofscanned = scanned.Count();
        progressBar1.Maximum = scanned.Length;

        foreach (string item in scanned)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (numofscanned); i++)
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler (backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
                worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);
            }              


        }
        foreach (string hashes in completehashes)
        {
            try
            {

                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(hashes);
                string read = stream.ReadToEnd();
                var lineCount = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Neil Bagley\Desktop\ProjectWork\VirusHashes\Test5.txt").Count();
                var virus = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Neil Bagley\Desktop\ProjectWork\VirusHashes\Test5.txt");
                foreach (string st in virus)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(read, st))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Virus Detected");
                        noofvirus += 1;
                        label2.Text = "Viruses: " + noofvirus.ToString();
                        listBox1.Items.Add(hashes);
                    }
                    progressBar1.Increment(1);
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                string read = hashes;
                var virus = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Neil Bagley\Desktop\ProjectWork\VirusHashes\Test5.txt");
                foreach (string st in virus)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(read, st))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Virus Detected");
                        noofvirus += 1;
                        label2.Text = "Viruses:" + noofvirus.ToString();
                        listBox1.Items.Add(hashes);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
    private static String MakeHashString(byte[] hashbytes)
    {
        StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder(32);

        foreach (byte b in hashbytes)
        {
            hash.Append(b.ToString("X2").ToLower());

        }
        return hash.ToString();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = e.Argument.ToString();
        byte[] buffer;
        int bytesRead;
        long size;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                size = file.Length;

                using (HashAlgorithm hasher = MD5.Create())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        buffer = new byte[4096];

                        bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                        hasher.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);


                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((double)totalBytesRead / size * 100));


                    } while (bytesRead != 0);

                    hasher.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);

                    e.Result = MakeHashString(hasher.Hash);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File not found in the specified path" + filePath);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IOException");
        }


    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        completehashes.Add(e.Result.ToString());

        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }





    }
}
```

After the advice previously given i have tried to start remaking the project, but im now unsure why this only adds one hash to the listbox rather all as i expected with "foreach (string scan in scanned)" can anyone explain?
New Attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AntiVirus
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int noofvirus = 0;        
        private string[] scanned;
        private void BBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        label1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        noofvirus = 0;
        label2.Text = "Viruses:" + noofvirus.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;            
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        scanned = Directory.GetFiles(e.Argument.ToString(), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


        foreach (string scan in scanned)
        {                
            byte[] buffer;
            int bytesRead;
            long size;
            long totalBytesRead = 0;

            using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(scan))
            {
                size = file.Length;

                using (HashAlgorithm hasher = MD5.Create())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        buffer = new byte[4096];

                        bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                        hasher.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);


                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((double)totalBytesRead / size * 100));


                    } while (bytesRead != 0);

                    hasher.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);

                    e.Result = MakeHashString(hasher.Hash);

                }
            }                
        }


    }
    private static String MakeHashString(byte[] hashbytes)
    {
        StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder(32);

        foreach (byte b in hashbytes)
        {
            hash.Append(b.ToString("X2").ToLower());

        }
        return hash.ToString();
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(e.Result.ToString());
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }

    private void BScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
    }

    private void BDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


   }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `vb.net`? And please trim down your code to only what matters.

Comment: Too much code. Try to reproduce in a minimal program, most likely you will find the error along the way.

Comment: the only thing really standing out is `worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);` with i being a integer that gets turned into a string `string filePath = e.Argument.ToString();` and then read `File.OpenRead(filePath)` though i'm mostly doing VB.NET coding so i could be reading that wrong.

Comment: thanks for your input, Ive removed the vb-tag that was mistake.
I included the full program so people could understand its full context.

Yeah Raphael your thinking along the same lines as i am, im just not sure how to correct the problem. because  i need it to iterate through.

Comment: it would require a major refactor/rewrite(though its not alot of code, so its doable) you could pass the `RunWorkerAsync` the root directory that needs to be scanned and just run the `BackgroundWorker` once doing all that needs to be done, iterating through all the files and using `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` to report to the UI thread when a file is scanned and if its clean or not, well that would be how i would do it, generally creating alot of `BackgroundWorker`s is not the best method.

Comment: Hi all
I have tried to go back to basics and reproduce what you suggested in my new code above but the for each loop appears not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You set `e.Result` for each hash, but only when the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is fired does it get added to the listbox.
(that event only fires once when the `DoWork` Event has completed, so only the last hash gets added)

I would recommand using `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress` 2nd parameter `userState` when you've got the file hash like so:
(note, code is untested/psuedocode but it hopefully gets you on the right track)

```
//CalculateTotalProgress() is a fictional function returning total progress percentage
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CalculateTotalProgress(currentFile,totalFiles), MakeHashString(hasher.Hash));


private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString);
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```